# Building a radio telescope!

Tags: astronomy, telescopes, radio-frequency, radio

So, I saw recently the idea of a radio telescope and thought how simple they are. So, like any other normal human being, I went on google and searched "how to make a radio telescope" and boom! Almost nothing! Why? I'm pretty sure it isn't classified, nor complicated. Why isn't there any information about making a radio telescope? As a radio amateur myself, I see it as quite strange.

So, anyone willing to provide any ideas on how to make it? Maybe someone will write an article about it somewhere sometime in the near future!

Till now, I know I need these:

- A receiver for 1240 MHz (I could try to make it but I have doubts I'll manage since the highest frequency receiver I made was 14 MHz for a ham band)
- An antenna (easily scavenged from old satellite tv gear)
- An amplifier (got one that goes up to 10 GHz and gives around 3-4 dB)
- A pc to plot the data

So, I need some help with the receiver, and maybe antenna (modifying it) and some work on the receiver-pc line.

Comment: why 1240MHz? You want a to observe a reasonably "clean" frequency band not contaminated by terrestrial RF noise. There are bands allocated to radio astronomy, see the table in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_astronomy . You will need a very clean and very stable receiver for the signal you are trying receive is very weak. Also use a very directional antenna with as small side and backlobes as possible to minimize the noise from the earth, and never look in to the sun.

Comment: 1240 i read its the hydrogen line, and i heard its the most used in radio astronomy , now idk , not alot of data about it.

Comment: Hi, CallMePluto, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. I have a few different comments - not sure that the question is on-topic; it seems a bit broad (it would be best if you restricted it to a very specific technical question, rather than a general call for advice) - but I also want to mention that the hyperfine transition leads to a hydrogen line at 1420 MHz, not 1240 MHz.

Comment: https://physicsopenlab.org/2020/10/10/a-simple-11-2-ghz-radiotelescope/